# How can I use Linq to extract this data from a List?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of the following:

```
Id: Game-1
GameType: Battlefield3
LogEntries: (an IList<LogEntry>)
  - Id: 1, Foo: Blah blah blah..
  - Id: 231, Foo: Blah blah blah..
  - Id: 342321, Foo: Blah blah blah..

Id: Game-2
GameType: Battlefield3
LogEntries: null

Id: Game-1
GameType: Battlefield3
LogEntries: (an IList<LogEntry>)
  - Id: 2121, Foo: Blah blah blah..
  - Id: 21333321, Foo: Blah blah blah..
```

etc.
So each game server can have 0 to many log entries.

Now, i'm trying to get the results in the following format.

```
IList<LogEntries> logEntries = <some linq magic>

Id: 1, Foo: Blah blah blah..
Id: 231, Foo: ....
Id: 2121, Foo: ....
Id: 342321, Foo: ....
Id: 342321, Foo: ....
```

So the log entries are ordered by Id.

Comment: Answering gets a lot easier when you post (simplified) class definitions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want:

```
IList<LogEntries> logEntries = games.SelectMany(game => game.LogEntries ?? Enumerable.Empty<LogEntry>())
                                    .OrderBy(logEntry => logEntry.Id)
                                    .ToList();
```

The key here is `SelectMany` operator, which *maps* each game to its log-entries and *flattens* the sequence of log-entry sequences to a simple sequence of log-entries.

You can also do this in query syntax:

```
var logEntries = from game in games
                 from logEntry in game.LogEntries ?? Enumerable.Empty<LogEntry>()                  
                 orderby logEntry.Id
                 select logEntry;
```

(You can call `ToList()` on the above to materialize the query to a list).

Personally though, I would change the `Game` type such that its `LogEntries` property could never be `null`, so you don't need to resort to `null` filtering gymnastics like the ones above.